# Edge density of graph

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

I've started reading *Graph Regularity Lemma* but the author starts with the notion of edge density.

> **Definition** (Edge density)
>
> Let $X$ and $Y$ be sets of vertices in a graph $G$. Let $e_G(X,Y)$ be
> the number of edges  between $X$ and $Y$; that is,
> $$e_G(X,Y):=|\{(x,y)\in X\times Y: xy\in E(G)\}|.$$ Define the ***edge
> density*** between $X$ and $Y$ in $G$ by
> $$d_G(X,Y):=\frac{e_G(X,Y)}{|X||Y|}.$$
> We allow $X$ and $Y$ to overlap in the definition above.

But I do not think that $e_G(X,Y)$ defined above counts the number of edges between $X$ and $Y$.
Indeed, if we take a look at the following graph: the number of edges here is actually 7. But the formula give 8 because it double counts the edge 34.

I am wondering is that normal that the formula double counts some edges?

[image]

Comment: From an intuition perspective, the definition given here allows the edge density of a complete graph with itself to tend to $1$ as $n$ tends to infinity, if you don't double count then it would tend to $\frac{1}{2}$ instead. This means that if the sets have large overlap but all the edges in the overlap are present the edge density doesn't get pulled down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the context of the regularity lemma, $X$ and $Y$ will be disjoint, so $e_G(X,Y)$ counts the number of edges between $X$ and $Y$.

It is very rare that $e_G(X,Y)$ is considered when $X \cap Y \ne \varnothing$. In such cases, I imagine it would be defined to be consistent with whatever you consider the actual number of edges between $X$ and $Y$ to be. (Edges with both endpoints in $X$ and $Y$ are a bit weird, in that case, and I expect that in different situations, we also want the definition to be different.)

The most important think about the definition is that we define edge density so that it is $1$ in a complete graph and $0$ in an empty graph. This is true in the quoted definition whether or not $X$ and $Y$ are disjoint. If we wanted to count the edges differently, it would probably be fine, provided we adjusted the denominator of $d_G(X,Y)$ appropriately.

Comment: Strictly it is only true asymptotically that the edge density of a complete graph is $1$ for any pair of subsets. For small complete graphs it fails when the sets chosen aren't disjoint (technically it always fails if the sets aren't disjoint, but the error is guaranteed to get very small for large graphs).

Comment: @Fishbane Hm, that's true. Possibly, when subsets aren't disjoint, I would want to pretend that all the vertices in $X \cap Y$ have self-loops for the density. Or maybe the asymptotic density being $1$ would be fine - it's hard to say in the abstract without knowing what the density will be useful for.

Comment: Indeed, in the case of Regularity Lemma we consider partition of a vertex set $V(G)$ of graph $G$. In that case, if $U\cap W=\varnothing$, then $e_G(U,W)$ is equal to the actual number of edges between $U$ and $W$. My question was if $U\cap W\neq \varnothing$, then the formula $e_G(U,W)$ defined above is wrong, right?

Comment: It's wrong in that it does not give the number of edges between $U$ and $W$, yes. (My only quibbles are that when $U \cap W \ne \varnothing$, who knows what the quantity we actually want to measure is.)

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I really do not know why the author says that we can allow the case when $X$ and $Y$ overlap. It definitely dies not make sense!

Comment: In your first paragraph you said "In the context of the regularity lemma, $X$ and $Y$ will be disjoint, so $e_G(X,Y)$ counts the number of edges between $X$ and $Y$." I don't that this is true because when I read the proof of Regularity Lemma they also deal with the edge density of $U,W$ where $U$ and $W$ can overlap. I know that you don't like when someone advertise question through comment but take a look at this post https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4560083/lemmas-towards-szemer%c3%a9di-regularity-lemma

Comment: I have not ever really looked closely at the proof of the regularity lemma. In applications of the lemma, $X$ and $Y$ are certainly always disjoint.