# Lemmas towards Szemerédi regularity lemma

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, additive-combinatorics

I have couple of questions about lemmas which lead to the proof of *Szemeredi's Graph Regularity Lemma*. I am using the book of Y.Zhao ["Graph Theory and Additive Combinatorics"](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4559829/the-number-of-edges-between-two-subsets-of-vertex-set-of-a-graph). First of all I need to provide some basic definitions.

> **Definition 2.1.10** (Energy)
>
> Let $G$ be an $n$-vertex graph. Let $U,W\subseteq V(G)$. Define
> $$q(U,W):=\frac{|U||W|}{n^2}d(U,W)^2.$$ For partitions
> $\mathcal{P}_{U}=\{U_1,\dots,U_k\}$ of $U$ and
> $\mathcal{P_W}=\{W_1,\dots,W_l\}$ of $W$, define
> $$q(\mathcal{P}_U,\mathcal{P}_W):=\sum
>  \limits_{i=1}^{k}\sum_{j=1}^{l}q(U_i,W_j).$$ Finally, for a partition
> $\mathcal{P}=\{V_1,\dots,V_k\}$ of $V(G)$, define its **energy** to be
> $$q(\mathcal{P}):=q(\mathcal{P},\mathcal{P})=\sum
>  \limits_{i,j=1}^{k}q(V_i,V_j)=\sum
>  \limits_{i,j=1}^{k}\frac{|V_i||V_j|}{n^2}d(V_i,V_j)^2.$$

> **Lemma 2.1.11** (Energy never decreases under refinement) Let $G$ be a graph, $U,W\subseteq V(G)$, $\mathcal{P}_U$ a partition of $U$, and
> $\mathcal{P}_W$ a partition of $W$. Then
> $q(\mathcal{P}_U,\mathcal{P}_W)\geq q(U,W).$
>
> *Proof.* Let $n=\nu(G)$. Let $\mathcal{P}_U=\{U_1,\dots,U_k\}$ and $\mathcal{P}_W=\{W_1,\dots,W_l\}$. Choose $x\in U$ and $y\in W$
> uniformly and independently at random. Let $U_i$ be the part of
> $\mathcal{P}_U$ that contains $x$ and $W_j$ be the part of
> $\mathcal{P}_W$ that contains $y$. Define the random variable
> $Z:=d(U_i,W_j)$. We have
> $$\mathbb{E}[Z]=\sum_{i=1}^{k}\sum_{j=1}^{l}\frac{|U_i||W_j|}{|U||W|}d(U_i,W_j)=d(U,W)=\sqrt{\frac{n^2}{|U||W|}q(U,W)}.$$
> We have
> $$\mathbb{E}[Z^2]=\sum_{i=1}^{k}\sum_{j=1}^{l}\frac{|U_i||W_j|}{|U||W|}d(U_i,W_j)^2=\frac{n^2}{|U||W|}q(\mathcal{P}_U,\mathcal{P}_W).$$
> By convexity, $\mathbb{E}[Z^2]\geq \mathbb{E}[Z]^2$, which implies
> $q(\mathcal{P}_U,\mathcal{P}_W)\geq q(U,W)$.

**Important remark:** I want to emphasize that actually $\mathbb{E}[Z]\geq d(U,W)$. Please see my [previous post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4559829/the-number-of-edges-between-two-subsets-of-vertex-set-of-a-graph). Anyway it does not change the proof. However, I guess it affects the proof of Lemma 2.1.13. See the details below.

> **Lemma 2.1.12** (Energy never decreases under refinement) Given two vertex partitions $\mathcal{P}$ and $\mathcal{P}'$ of some graph, if
> $\mathcal{P}'$ refines $\mathcal{P}$, then $q(\mathcal{P})\leq
>  q(\mathcal{P}').$
>
> *Proof.* Follows easily from the previous lemma (or see the book).

> **Lemma 2.1.13** (Energy boost for an irregular pair) Let $G$ be an $n$-vertex graph. If $(U,W)$ is not $\varepsilon$-regular, as
> witnessed by $A\subseteq U$ and $B\subseteq W$, then
> $$q(\{A,U\setminus A\},\{B,W\setminus B\})>q(U,W)+\varepsilon^4
>  \frac{|U||W|}{n^2}.$$
>
> *Proof.*
>
> Define $Z$ as in the proof of Lemma 2.1.11 for
> $\mathcal{P}_U=\{A,U\setminus A\}$ and $\mathcal{P}_W=\{B,W\setminus
>  B\}$. Then
> $$\text{Var}(Z)=\mathbb{E}[Z^2]-\mathbb{E}[Z]^2=\frac{n^2}{|U||W|}(q(\mathcal{P}_U,\mathcal{P}_W)-q(U,W)).$$
> We have $Z=d(A,B)$ with probability $\geq |A||B|/(|U||W|)$
> (corresponding to the event $x\in A$ and $y\in B$). So
> $$\text{Var}(Z)=\mathbb{E}[(Z-\mathbb{E}[Z])^2]\geq
>  \frac{|A||B|}{|U||W|}(d(A,B)-d(U,W))^2>\varepsilon \cdot \varepsilon
>  \cdot \varepsilon^2.$$ Putting the inequalities together gives the
> claim.

But if we take into account what I wrote in the **Important remark** this proof does not work out.
Indeed, we'll get that $\text{Var}(Z)\leq \frac{n^2}{|U||W|}(q(\mathcal{P}_U,\mathcal{P}_W)-q(U,W)).$ But the lower bound for $\text{Var}(Z)$ which I wrote above is not true anymore.

**EDIT.** My remark tells us that $$\text{Var}(Z)=\mathbb{E}[Z^2]-\mathbb{E}[Z]^2\leq \frac{n^2}{|U||W|}\left(q(\mathcal{P}_U,\mathcal{P}_W)-q(U,W) \right).$$
On the other hand, $$\text{Var}(Z)=\mathbb{E}[\underbrace{(Z-\mathbb{E}[Z])^2}_{\xi}]=\sum_{\omega\in \Omega}\xi(\omega)\mathbb{P}(\omega)\geq \sum_{\omega\in A\times B}\xi(\omega)\mathbb{P}(\omega).$$
We notice that here $\Omega:=U\times W$ is the probability space and $\forall \omega \in \Omega\quad \mathbb{P}[\omega]=\frac{1}{|U||W|}$. We notice that for each $\omega\in A\times B$, we have $\xi(\omega)=(Z(\omega)-\mathbb{E}[Z])^2=(d(A,B)-\mathbb{E}[Z])^2$. All this implies that $$\text{Var}(Z)\geq (d(A,B)-\mathbb{E}[Z])^2\frac{|A||B|}{|U||W|}.$$ From Lemma 2.1.11 we know that $\mathbb{E}[Z]\geq d(U,W)$ and we see that it does not imply what we want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Yufei Zhao's book, the quantity $e_G(X, Y)$ is defined as follows ([Definition 2.1.1](https://yufeizhao.com/gtacbook/gtacbook.pdf)):

$$
e_G(X, Y) := |\{(x,y)\in X\times Y : xy \in E(G)\}|.
$$
This means if $a,b \in X\cap Y$ and $ab \in E(G)$ then the edge $ab$ it is counted twice in $e_G(X,Y)$. With this convention you will have $\mathbb{E}[Z] = d(U,W)$.

Clarification: You are correct that $e_G$ is not the number of edges. It is a little bit different but if you take the above display as definition of $e_G$ then the proof goes through as it is. Again, it is NOT the number of edges, and that sentence is an oversight in Yufei's book I believe. Let me know if this clarifies your doubts.

Comment: The way he defined the $e_G(X,Y)$ is not correct at all  if $X$ and $Y$ overlap. See here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4553699/edge-density-of-graph

Comment: Well, I am unsure what you mean by "not correct" but I do not see anything wrong either.

Comment: Probably you did not open the link in the previous comment. The point is the following: he defined $e_G(X,Y)$ as the number of edges between $X$ and $Y$. Then he writes that $e_G(X,Y):=|\{(x,y)\in X\times Y: xy\in E(G)\}|$. Look if $X$ and $Y$ overlap and suppose that $a,b\in X\cap Y$ and $ab\in E(G)$, then $e_G(X,Y)$ which is the actual number of edges between $X$ and $Y$ is not the equal to $|\{(x,y)\in X\times Y: xy\in E(G)\}|$.

Comment: For example, if $X=\{1,2,4\}\subseteq V(G)$ and $Y=\{2,3,4\}\subseteq V(G)$, where $G=K_4$ with vertex set $\{1,2,3,4\}$. Then one can check that $e_G(X,Y)=6$ but $|\{(x,y)\in X\times Y: xy\in E(G)\}|=7$. Does it make sense now?

Comment: Am I missing something? I’d be very grateful to you if you can help me.

Comment: As I have mentioned in the answer, $e_G$ is not counting the number of edges by Yufei's definition. If you assume the definition of $e_G(X,Y)$ as it is (counting the edges in $X \cap Y$ twice) then I do not see anything wrong in Yufei's argument. This convention is actually not that uncommon (see page 5 here https://people.math.ethz.ch/~sudakovb/pseudo-random-survey.pdf). Best

Comment: Sorry but I'm still confused. So what is $e_G(X,Y)$? He writes that it is the number of edges between $X$ and $Y$ but you wrote that $e_G$ is not counting the number of edges. I am wondering can you give more detailed answer please? I'll appreciate it! Thanks!

Comment: The actual precise definition is as Suman writes. Zhao speaks informally of it as 'the number of edges', but this is with some edges being double-counted. Again as Suman says, this is a standard convention in the field. Just work with the precise definition throughout and everything should be fine.

Comment: @ThomasBloom, indeed if we let $e_G(X,Y):=|\{(x,y)\in X\times Y: xy\in E(G)\}|$, then everything works out. After couple days of deep thought I realized that. One thing which is bothering and which I underlined couple times above is the fact that $e_G(X,Y)$ defined in this way does not give the actual number of edges between $X$ and $Y$, if there is some edge with endpoints in $X\cap Y$.

Comment: @ZFR I have tried to clarify my answer, and since you have pointed out this oversight (although minor), maybe you can write a line to Yufei. Best

Comment: Thank you! Now it makes sense. I think that I'll accept your answer and give you a bounty. But let me ask you the following general question: as we see when we define $e_G(X,Y):=|\{(x,y)\in X\times Y: xy\in E(G)\}|$ we can have a double counting of some edges so this actually does not count the number of edges between $X$ and $Y$. But if $X\cap Y=\varnothing$, then it perfectly makes sense. In the applications of Szemeredi Graph Regularity Lemma are these $X$ and $Y$ disjoint or not?

Comment: Because this double counting actually looks a bit confusing since it double counts some edges and does not the other edges. I hope that my question is clear. Thank you!

Comment: In the statement of the Szemeredi's lemma (for example Theorem 2.1.9 in Yufei's book), it says "...every graph has an $\epsilon$-regular partition into at most $M$ parts." Partition means that the parts are disjoint. In applications, sometimes you can assume that parts are disjoint without losing much (sometimes you can modify the graph a little bit to impose disjointness). You can start reading counting lemma and removal lemma. I will suggest that you also take a look at the beautiful survey by Komlos and Simonovits to learn more about many applications.

Comment: @SumanChakraborty, thank you so much! Yeah, I will start reading traingle counting lemma and triangle removal lemma. It is interesting to know how they apply these results to prove Roth's theorem. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Dear Suman! Sorry to bother you but I am wondering can you take a look at my last question please? Here is the link: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4581259/question-about-szemeredi-graph-regularity-lemma I keep working on this but I failed to understand it! I'll highy appreciate your help! Thank you!