# Question about Szemeredi Graph Regularity Lemma

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, extremal-combinatorics, extremal-graph-theory

The below argument is from Zhao's book "Graph Theory and Additive Combinatorics".

> **Definition 2.1.2** ($\varepsilon$-regular pair)
>
> Let $G$ be a graph and $U,W\subseteq V(G)$. We call $(U,W)$ an
> $\varepsilon$-***regular pair*** in $G$ if for all $A\subseteq U$ and
> $B\subseteq W$ with $|A|\geq \varepsilon |U|$ and $|B|\geq \varepsilon
>  |W|$, one has  $$|d(A,B)-d(U,W)|\leq \varepsilon.$$ If $(U,W)$ is not
> $\varepsilon$-regular, then we say that their irregularity is
> **witnessed** by some $A\subseteq U$ and $B\subseteq W$ satisfying
> $|A|\geq \varepsilon |U|$, $|B|\geq \varepsilon |W|$, and
> $|d(A,B)-d(U,W)|> \varepsilon.$

> **Definition 2.1.7** ($\varepsilon$-regular partition)
>
> Given a graph $G$, a partition $\mathcal{P}=\{V_1,\dots,V_k\}$ of its
> vertex set is an $\varepsilon$-**regular partition** if
> $$\sum_{\substack{(i,j)\in [k]^2\\\text{$(V_i,V_j)$ not
>  $\varepsilon$-regular}}}|V_i||V_j|\leq \varepsilon |V(G)|^2.$$

Now we can formulate Regularity Lemma:

> **Theorem 2.1.9 (Szemeredi's graph regularity lemma)** For every $\varepsilon>0$, there exists a constant $M$ such that every graph
> has an $\varepsilon$-regular partition into at most $M$ parts.

In order to prove this fundamental result we need to introduce the following definition:

> **Definition 2.1.10** (Energy)
>
> Let $G$ be an $n$-vertex graph. Let $U,W\subseteq V(G)$. Define
> $$q(U,W):=\frac{|U||W|}{n^2}d(U,W)^2,$$ where $d(U,W)$ is an *edge density* between $U$ and $W$.
>
> For partitions
> $\mathcal{P}_{U}=\{U_1,\dots,U_k\}$ of $U$ and
> $\mathcal{P_W}=\{W_1,\dots,W_l\}$ of $W$, define
> $$q(\mathcal{P}_U,\mathcal{P}_W):=\sum
>  \limits_{i=1}^{k}\sum_{j=1}^{l}q(U_i,W_j).$$ Finally, for a partition
> $\mathcal{P}=\{V_1,\dots,V_k\}$ of $V(G)$, define its **energy** to be
> $$q(\mathcal{P}):=q(\mathcal{P},\mathcal{P})=\sum
>  \limits_{i,j=1}^{k}q(V_i,V_j)=\sum
>  \limits_{i,j=1}^{k}\frac{|V_i||V_j|}{n^2}d(V_i,V_j)^2.$$

Since the edge density is always between $0$ and $1$, we have $0\leq q(\mathcal{P})\leq 1$ for all partitions $\mathcal{P}$.

The following lemma plays an important role in the proof of Graph Regularity Lemma.

> **Lemma 2.1.14** (Energy boost for an irregular partition) If a partition $\mathcal{P}=\{V_1,\dots,V_k\}$ of $V(G)$ is not
> $\varepsilon$-regular, then there exists a refinement $\mathcal{Q}$ of
> $\mathcal{P}$ where every $V_i$ is partitioned into at most $2^{k+1}$
> parts, and such that $$q(\mathcal{Q})>q(\mathcal{P})+\varepsilon^5.$$

*Proof of the graph regularity lemma (Theorem 2.1.9).* Start with a trivial partition of the
vertex set of the graph. Repeatedly apply Lemma 2.1.14 whenever the current partition is
not $\varepsilon$-regular. By Lemma 2.1.14, the energy of the partition increases by more than $\varepsilon^5$ at each iteration. Since the energy of the partition is $\leq 1$, we must stop after $<\varepsilon^{-5}$ iterations, terminating in an $\varepsilon$-regular partition.

If a partition has $k$ parts, then Lemma 2.1.14 produces a refinement with $\leq k2^{k+1}$ parts. We start with a trivial partition with one part, and then refine $<\varepsilon^{-5}$ times. Observe the crude bound $k2^{k+1}\leq2^{2^k}$. So the total number of parts at the end is $\leq \text{tower}(\lceil 2\varepsilon^{-5}\rceil)$ (In the book author writes ceiling function, but I believe one can take floor function as well, i.e. I mean that the total number of parts at the end is $\leq \text{tower}(\lfloor 2\varepsilon^{-5}\rfloor)$), where
$$\text{tower}(k):=2^{2^{.^{.^{.^{2}}}}} \Bigg\} \text{height $k$}$$

**Question:**

> The regularity lemma is quite flexible. For example, we can start with
> an arbitrary partition of $V(G)$ instead of the trivial partition in
> the proof, in order to obtain a partition that is a refinement of a
> given partition. The exact same proof with this modification yields
> the following.

> **Theorem 2.1.19** (Regularity starting with an arbitrary intiial partition)
>
> For every $\varepsilon>0$, there exists a constant $M$ such that for
> every graph $G$ and a partition $\mathcal{P}_0$ of $V(G)$, there
> exists an $\varepsilon$-regular partition $\mathcal{P}$ of $V(G)$ that
> is a refinement of $\mathcal{P}_0$, and such that each part of
> $\mathcal{P}_0$ is refined into at most $M$ parts.

I don't think that it follows easily and directly as we did in original formulation of regularity lemma. This is what I've done so far. Let $\varepsilon>0$ be given and take any graph $G$ and fix some partition $\mathcal{P}_0=\{V_1,\dots,V_k\}$ of $V(G)$. If $\mathcal{P}_0$ is $\varepsilon$-regular, then we are done. Otherwise, we apply Lemma 2.1.14  and obtain a partition $\mathcal{P}_1$ of $V(G)$ which refines $\mathcal{P}_0$ such that $|\mathcal{P}_1|\leq k2^{k+1}$ and $q(\mathcal{P}_1)>q(\mathcal{P}_0)+\varepsilon^5$. By the same reasoning at the $N$th step we have an $\varepsilon$-partition $\mathcal{P}_N$, where $N<\varepsilon^{-5}$ and $$|\mathcal{P}_N|\leq 2^{2^{\dots^{2^k}}} \Bigg \} \text{height $(2N+1)$}.$$
But we see that the size of $\mathcal{P}_N$ depends depends also on $k=|\mathcal{P}_0|$. We know that $2N+1\leq \lfloor 2\varepsilon^{-5}\rfloor+1$. But I am wondering is it possible to give an upper bound for $k$ in terms of $\varepsilon$?

Can anyone help me please?

**P.S.** Unfortunately, my edit was wrong so I've decided to give bounty on this question. I worked hard on this question for 3-4 days but I don't know the answer.

<s>**EDIT:** I think that I understood the claim. It was much simpler than I thought before. Suppose we fix some partition $\mathcal{P}_0$ of $V(G)$. We already know that if we start from trivial partition, then we end up in $\varepsilon$-regular partition (say $\mathcal{P}'$) in fewer than $\text{tower}(\lfloor 2\varepsilon^{-5} \rfloor)$ steps. However, if we intersect $\mathcal{P}_0$ with partitions (by intersection I mean a common refinement of two partitions) at each step and since energy does not decrease under refinement, then we still obtain an $\varepsilon$-regular partition which refines $\mathcal{P_0}$ and the number of parts in this partition is $\leq |\mathcal{P}_0|\text{tower}(\lfloor 2\varepsilon^{-5} \rfloor)$. Does it make sense?</s>

Comment: Good question. I'm checking with the author right now.

Comment: @ShengtongZhang, thanks a lot for your attention to my question! Appreciate it! In the book when author proves Szemeredi regularity Lemma he writes that the number of parts is $\leq \text{tower}(\lceil 2\varepsilon^{-5}\rceil)$. But am I right that one can takes $\leq \text{tower}(\lfloor 2\varepsilon^{-5}\rfloor)$? I think we can because $N<\varepsilon^{-5}$.

Comment: Of course, you can.

Comment: @ShengtongZhang, thank you for your reply! I appreciate your time and help! +1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct in pointing out a mistake in the statement. The resulting number of parts depends on the number of parts in the initial partition. I will make a correction.

Comment: Dear Prof. Zhao! Thanks a lot for your reply! +1